# Ms Access further details on Pivot column

Tags: ms-access, pivot

I have the following ms access table:

[image]

Based on the previous table, I could successfully create a pivot as the following picture shows:[image]

My concern now is: Is it possible to include section column count as further details of dep column?

Results required as the following image:

[image]

I appears to be a pivot inside pivot but dont know how to do it. Or, it might be possible by creating report only not pivot query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate Unit and Dept for your pivot:

```
Transform Count(section)
SELECT Unit
From MyTable
GROUP BY Unit
PIVOT (dep & "_" & Unit)
```

Comment: This still returns (dep & "_" & Unit) as one column. Have a look again to the picture for the required solution

Comment: Well, this isn't Excel. You can't have spanning columns. Please provide a required solution that's actually possible within Access.

Comment: I was curious if that actually possible! Are you saying that it is possible with excel?

Comment: Having spanning columns, yes. Executing complex queries, kind of not Excel's strong suit, but the pivot table function might be sufficient.